# GViM: Test if any menus have been created and/or visible?

Tags: vim

While `has("menu")` can tell me if gvim will support the menu command, is there a way to test in vim script if *any* menu currently exists?

The closest thing that I could figure out is to execute the `:menu` command and count the output.  For example, in rough pseudo code...

```
  if count(":menu") != '0'
     " something has created a menu and is visible on screen
  else
     " no menus have been created
  endif
```

Comment: Please tell us _why_ you need to know this; there may be a better approach. I for one cannot imagine a use case; there's always the built-in menu, and adding menu items should be cummulative, regardless of what other plugins have added.

Comment: I populate the vim menu dynamically depending on a combination of plugins and the type of file that I'm editing.  In some cases there are no menu items created and I would like to test for this condition in vim script.

Comment: Not having a menu is not an issue. Setting it will always override its value, and clearing it the opposite. Now, if you want to do smarter things, you'll have to track "manually" what menu you have created. That's what have been done in buffermenu (http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/misc/trunk/plugin/buffermenu.vim), Or what I've done in my togglable-options-through-menus-and-commands (http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhVimLib#Menus_related_functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is unusual; that's why menu items probably aren't covered by `exists()` or a function analog to `maparg()`.

You have to do this as outlined in your pseudo code:

```
redir => menuOutput
silent! menu
redir END

if menuOutput =~# '--- Menus ---\n$'
    " no menus
endif
```

---

<sup>PS: Overreliance on menus is a Vim "smell"; for one, you don't have them (easily accessible) when using console Vim.</sup>